# How to Upload video file of 1GB + within 2 mins using PHP platform

Tags: php

I m trying to upload a Video of 1 GB to a website i built.

However, the file uploads but it takes around 55 mins for 1 GB file. How can i reduce the time taking to 2 mins.

Here's my usual file upload code.

```
<?php include('db'); ?>
<?php include('index.php'); ?>
<?php

 $title = $_POST['title'];
 $description = $_POST['description'];
 $tag= $_POST['tag'];
 $category = $_POST['category'];
 $status = 'offline';
 $file=($_FILES['file']['name']);
 $id = $_POST['u_id'];

 $conn = new mysqli ($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}




     $sql2 = "INSERT INTO table(m_id, title, description, tag, vid, category, status, date)
            VALUES ('$id', '$title', '$description', '$tag', '$file', '$category', '$status', '$date2')";
            if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {



            $target_dir = "mainimages/vids/";
$target_file2 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk2 = 1;
$imageFileType2 = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file2,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if ($uploadOk2 == 0) {


// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file2)) {


    echo '<script language="javascript">';
                    echo 'alert("file Successfully Uploaded .")';
                    echo '</script>';
                    echo '<a href="index.php"></a>';


} else {


    }
}

            }
            else {
                echo "ERROR" . $sql2 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }

?>
```

So,basically, i just need a solution where the file i upload will gets uploaded in less time.

I thought of Hosting Bandwith  Or the Network i connected to as of the lagging possibilities but

even with the good bandwith and network i still get the same problem..

How do i overcome.

Comment: you would need an upstream of at least 4 gbit/s

Comment: Or a compression algorithm that reduces the file until the size suits the bandwidth... Probably impossible to achieve...

Comment: The user, the server, **and** the network between them will need at least four gigabits per second worth of bandwidth available. This will basically be never, at least in 2019. Demanding this be uploaded in two minutes is like trying to push a human through a wine bottle.

Answer (score 0):

Your script looks fine. In case your script would not work, you cannot see your video on the server. Based on your question, I assume you can see the video on your server (after an hour).

You can compare your problem with the sewer: there is a maximum capacity. This is for you internet-connection, as well the server. For now, I see three options:

1. Speed up your internet-connection.
2. Speed up your server-connection.
3. Compress the video, so the file-size would be smaller.

Tim